# Should I close a question with a silly error but some code involved who can potentially be useful (or maybe not)?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, close-reasons

I made a silly typo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251670/depencency-injection-constructors-with-dependencies-with-parameters), but beside that the code works and might be helpful. Better delete the question, auto answer or vote to close it?